# PHP Syntax Error when reading STDIN

Tags: php, syntax-error, stdin

I'm building a CLI script in PHP that needs to read the content from STDIN and process it into a variable. It is executable, but the result is the same calling as argument for the "php" command.

It is a script that runs triggered by a WHM event hook.

Here is the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

$switches = (count($argv) > 1) ? $argv : array();

if (in_array('--describe', $switches)) {
    echo json_encode(describe());
    exit;
} elseif (in_array('--debug', $switches)) {
    list($status, $msg) = debug();
    echo "$status $msg";
    exit;
} else {
    echo '0 myapp/whm.php needs a valid switch';
    exit(1);
}


function getStdInStream()
{
    $input   = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    $rawData = '';

    if (is_resource($input)) {
        stream_set_blocking($input, 0);

        while (($line = fgets($input, 1024)) !== false) {
            $rawData .= trim($line);
        }

        fclose($input);
    }

    if ($rawData) {
        $data = json_decode($rawData, true);
    } else {
        $data = array('context'=>array(), 'data'=>array(), 'hook'=>array());
    }

    return $data;
}

function describe()
{
    $debug = array(
        'category' => 'Cpanel',
        'event'    => 'UAPI::Branding::get_application_information',
        'stage'    => 'pre',
        'hook'     => '/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/hooktest --debug',
        'exectype' => 'script',
    );
    return array($debug);
}

function debug()
{
    $status = 1;
    $msg = 'Triggered!';

    $input = getStdInStream();

    return array($status, $msg);
}
```

Running this on the command line returns a syntax error message on the line 24:

```
$ /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/hooktest
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in  <b>/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/hooktest</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
```

I can't see anything wrong on the syntax. I have made some tests like comment the code inside the function `getStdInStream` and the error disappears.

That script is based on the example found here: 
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+Standardized+Hooks+-+Script+Hook+Action+Code

Tried commenting and uncommenting line by line and nothing works after the `fopen` being executed.

Do you have any idea why I can't read the STDIN using that approach, or if that is a PHP bug?

My PHP version:

```
PHP 5.4.41 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May 22 2015 16:12:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what seems to be a solution. 
Changing the hashbang from `#!/usr/bin/php -q` to `#!/usr/bin/env php` made PHP interpret the script differently.

I have noticed that using the original script (from the question) the global constants `STDIN` and `STDOUT` are not defined. Using the `#!/usr/bin/env php` solves that issue too.

According to the man pages for `env` it runs the program in a modified environment, instead of "just" pass the script to an interpreter (php on this case). What makes me think it properly redirects the `stdin` and `stdout` to the script code in the environment.